# python loops, 2 player game

Tags: python, loops

I'm working on finishing my first simple program in python, a 2 player (user vs computer AI) word/letter guessing game.

I've got the bulk of the code finished, but I'm trying to get my loops sorted out so that the game will properly alternate between the user and the AI. I want to make it so that the game alternates back and forth between user and AI turns, until the world has been fully revealed. At that point, the player to guess the most letters correctly wins a point. The computer moderator picks another word and starts again. The first player to five points wins the game.

I'm not sure where to start with this. I'm still quite new to python/coding in general and I have a difficult time understanding the order in which events occur. I know I need some kind of master loop that remains True as long as the word has yet to be fully revealed, but that's about it.

Also, any other suggestions as to how to optimize the code below or clean it up in anyway would be appreciated!

```
import random


#set initial values
player1points= 0
ai= 0
userCorrectLetters= ''
aiCorrectLetters=''
wrongLetters=''
wrongPlace= ''
correctLetters = ''
notInWord = ''
endGame = False
allLetters = set(list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))
alreadyGuessed = set() 
userGuessPosition = 0
availLetters = allLetters.difference(alreadyGuessed)


#import wordlist, create mask
with open('wordlist.txt') as wordList:
    secretWord = random.choice(wordList.readlines()).strip()
print (secretWord)
secretWordLength = len(secretWord)








def displayGame():
    mask = '_'  * len(secretWord)
    for i in range (len(secretWord)):
        if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
            mask = mask[:i] + secretWord[i] + mask [i+1:]
    for letter in mask:
        print (letter, end='')
    print (' ')
    print ('letters in word but not in correct location:', wrongPlace)
    print ('letters not in word:', wrongLetters)



    ##asks the user for a guess, assigns input to variable

def getUserGuess(alreadyGuessed):


    while True:
        print ('enter your letter')
        userGuess = input ()
        userGuess= userGuess.lower()
        if len(userGuess) != 1:
            print ('please enter only one letter')
        elif userGuess in alreadyGuessed:
            print ('that letter has already been guessed. try again')
        elif userGuess not in 'abcdefjhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print ('only letters are acceptable guesses. try again.')
        else:
            return userGuess

def newGame():
    print ('yay. that was great. do you want to play again? answer yes or no.')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')


userTurn=True     
while userTurn == True:
    displayGame ()
    print ('which character place would you like to guess. Enter number?')
    userGuessPosition = int(input())

    slice1 = userGuessPosition - 1  


    ##player types in letter
    guess = getUserGuess(wrongLetters + correctLetters)
    if guess== (secretWord[slice1:userGuessPosition]):
        correctLetters = correctLetters + guess
        print ('you got it right! ')
        displayGame()
        break
    elif guess in secretWord:
            wrongPlace = wrongPlace + guess 
            print ('that letter is in the word, but not in that position')
            displayGame()
            break
    else:
            wrongLetters = wrongLetters + guess
            print ('nope. that letter is not in the word')
            displayGame()
            break

print ("it's the computers turn")

aiTurn=True

while aiTurn == True:
    aiGuessPosition = random.randint(1, secretWordLength)
    print (aiGuessPosition)

    aiGuess=random.sample(availLetters, 1)
    print ('the computer has guessed', aiGuess, "in position", + aiGuessPosition)
    if str(aiGuess) == (secretWord[slice1:userGuessPosition]):
            correctLetters = correctLetters + guess
            print ('this letter is correct ')
            break
    elif str(aiGuess) in secretWord:
            aiCorrectLetters = aiCorrectLetters + guess 
            correctLetters = correctLetters + guess
            print ('that letter is in the word, but not in that position')
            break
    else:
            wrongLetters = wrongLetters + guess
            print ('that letter is not in the word')
            break   


    displayGame() 
    break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it will only do two turns and then exit?

What is happening is that it hits your first `while` loop, and starts to evaluate the code inside.  It does some stuff, and then hits the `break` which breaks you out of the loop and execution resume after the end of your first loop.  It then does the same thing with the second loop, hits the end of you program and exits.

I would suggest the following refactoring:

1. put all of the stuff you have under your `while` loops into two function `user_play` and `computer_play`
2. write a loop something like

this

```
usr_pts = 0
cmp_pts = 0

while (usr_pts < 5 and cmp_pts < 5):
    solved_word = False
    # set up word
    user_turn = False
    user_correct_guess = 0
    ai_correct_guess = 0
    while not solved_word:
        user_turn = not user_turn
        if user_turn:
            guess = play_user(...)
        else:
            guess = computer_play(...)
        # what ever accounting you need to do
        is_guess_in_word = test_guess_in_word(guess, ...)
        if is_guess_in_word:
            if user_turn:
                user_correct_guess += 1
            else:
                ai_correct_guess += 1
        solved_word = sort_out_if_word_solved(...)

    if user_correct_guess > ai_correct_guess:
        usr_pts += 1
    elif user_correct_guess < ai_correct_guess:
        cmp_pts +=1
    else:
        # a tie
        pass
```

Comment: currently, it only does two turns, not two rounds (a round being a full word correctly guessed).


Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it now.

Comment: @jamyn note I tweaked the logic a bit

Comment: Bear with me here, I'm still quite a beginner with coding--

During each "round", the computer and the AI should take turns guessing until the word is revealed. At which point, whoever has guessed more letters correctly wins the round. Winning a round should win a point.

from what I can tell of the code you provided, it looks like the computer and the AI are simply alternating rounds? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I may have misunderstood the rules of the game, this gives the point to who ever finished the word.  There are two loops, the outer on (which keeps going until someone has 5 points) and the inner one that keeps going until the word is guessed.

Comment: @jamyn As I assume you are doing this for educational purposes, the nested loop structure is the answer to the question you asked, it is your job to make the code in the loops do the right thing ;)

Comment: ahh, that's what I thought. Sorry if my initial description was unclear. The game should alternate turns between computer and AI, with each guessing one letter at a time until the word is completely unveiled. at this point, whoever has guessed more letters in the word wins the round (and thus, a point). The first player to 5 points wins. So, I'm assuming I need to put both of those functions (userTurn and aiTurn) into a while loop for the round, and then that loop would go into another while loop for the game as a whole?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27730/discussion-between-tcaswell-and-jamyn)